# 'dict' object does not support indexing in Airflow in creating a Data Source

Tags: flask, airflow

I installed an instance of Airflow in Ubuntu 16.04 and the login worked fine. Now I tried to create a data source out of Redshift. The test connection worked fine too. But when I tried to save the data source, I got this error:

```
'dict' object does not support indexing
```

I have no idea where this is coming from? Can this be from Flask? Please enlighten me!

Comment: You are using something like `myDict[5]` probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had to use "postgresql+psycopg2" connection string not "redshift+psycopg". It is still confusing to me that in my prior installation, the latter worked out fine.